# How to preview all UI elements/widgets and dialogs

Tags: themes

I need to view all the different UI elements and dialogs on a device. This would be helpful while developing new platform level themes.

Is there an existing app that will do this? Are there other ways to view all the UI elements (e.g. android.widget.Button, android.widget.CheckBox, etc).

Comment: We prefer questions that ask "how do I do X" rather than "is there an app that does X". That is, we prefer problems to solve rather than helping people "shop" for an app. While the solution may very well be an app, it's too limiting to make that a starting position and skirts far too closely to "shopping recommendations are off-topic".

Comment: @Al, updated the question wording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the Android API Samples.

The APIDemos application is exactly what you are looking for:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html

Comment: Thanks. This gets very close. Dialogs are covered pretty well and found most of the widgets under App/Activity/Animation (click on fade in or zoom in).